# WCAG - VoiceOver with chrome

Tags: html, macos, navigation, accessibility, wcag2.0

I started navigating through google website with VoiceOver enabled in my macbook(10.12.6) on google chrome(77.0.3865.90) by keyboard navigation. The black focus of the VoiceOver gets trapped at the "Customize and control Google chrome" option. Only the keyboard focus(blue color) navigates through the webElements of the page and VoiceOver not announces the webElements. But VoiceOver works fine in Safari browser...

And most of the keyboard hotkeys not works while try to access the content area...

Please suggest a solution for the above issues...

Comment: VoiceOver doesn't play well with Chrome. The solution is to use Safari. Alternatively put a Windows partition on your Macbook and use NVDA. Sorry to say there isn't a better option here.